# npm run dev error (windows)

Tags: laravel, windows, npm, webpack

Estoy trabajando con laravel y cuando hago quiero compilar y hago npm run dev, me sale este error una
y otra vez.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-02T16_52_11_692Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-02T16_52_11_795Z-debug.log
```

Este es mi archivos package.json:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
        
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "webpack": "^5.9.0"
    }
}
```

He intentado ya varias soluciones, como eliminar *package.lock.json* y la carpeta node modules y volver a instalar, también `npm install -g cross-env` o `npm update`. Y ninguna de ellas me ha funcionado. No sé que más probar...

¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmhh pareciera un error de corss-env

```
npm install --global cross-env
```

Pero si no te funciona te recomendaria eliminar caches en la medida de lo posible.
Muchas veces es algun paquete corrompido o alguna version erronea de algo.

1: composer update

2: rm -rf node_modules

3: npm cache clean

4: npm install

5: npm outdated

6: npm install

7: npm run dev

Comment: Hola. Probé todo lo indicado pero sigue dándome el error. La verdad que he probado diversas soluciones pero ninguna me funciona.